# only some functions of controller cannot access session data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i am new to codeigniter. i am setting the session in one controller. and i could access that session data from some functions of another controller. but only some functions cannot access the session data. please help me why this is happening.

i set the session by

```
$admin_details=array(
    'admin_id'=>$admin_id,
    'admin_name'=>$admin_name,
    'email'=>$email,
    'is_admin_logged_in'=>true,
    'user_type'=>'admin'
    );
$this->session->set_userdata($admin_details);
```

and i accessed it by

```
function manage_profile()
{

    if(!$this->session->userdata('is_admin_logged_in'))
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/test');
    }
}
```

but it is loading the view 'test'. i have loaded the session library and set the encryption key. it works in some other functions in the same controller.

Comment: dump your session array and see what it returns in manage_profile function

Comment: it returns..array(5) { ["session_id"]=> string(32) "2e75844ad3cccc256669c52d1a44bf90" ["ip_address"]=> string(15) "123.237.210.195" ["user_agent"]=> string(101) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36" ["last_activity"]=> int(1421305221) ["user_data"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Something from your code has unset the admin session. Is there any another code snippet that is intersecting to your code?

Comment: no. the admin session resetting is not done anywhere.. and the var_dump function in that function gives boolean FALSE

Comment: but still some other functions could access the session data

Comment: what is your $config['sess_expiration'] value in config file? If you are using an iframe and getting the contents using an ajax call this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you type `$this->session->userdata('is_admin_logged_in')` You're accessing the 'container' for the session.

`$admin_details=array(
    'admin_id'=>$admin_id,
    'admin_name'=>$admin_name,
    'email'=>$email,
    'is_admin_logged_in'=>true,
    'user_type'=>'admin'
    );
$this->session->set_userdata($admin_details);`

You actually need to do this:
`$this->session->set_userdata('name_your_session_something',$admin_details);`

Then to access it:

`$session = $this->session->userdata('name_your_session_something');
$admin_logged = $session['is_admin_logged_in'];`

`if(!$admin_logged){
//if admin is not logged in do this
}`

It's a simple array situation.

So this should be the code:

Set Session:

```
$admin_details=array( 
        'admin_id'=>$admin_id, 
        'admin_name'=>$admin_name, 
        'email'=>$email, 
        'is_admin_logged_in'=>true, 
        'user_type'=>'admin' 
);
$this->session->set_userdata('name_your_session_something',$admin_details);
```

Get Session:

```
$session = $this->session->userdata('name_your_session_something'); 
$admin_logged = $session['is_admin_logged_in'];
```

Comment: i tried $this->session->set_userdata('login_session',$admin_details); but it wont set the session data first.

Comment: Do you have `$this->load->library('session');` in your construct?
edit: i see you do, in both controllers?

Comment: the problem is when i call this function ie., manage_profile(), the session unset automatically.. note: i am calling this function from an iframe

Comment: Are you doing `$this->manage_profile`? Also edited above, just check that is what you have. And if it's not the code that's in your question, can you post the code that is the problem?

Comment: i cannot access any session data in the iframe. is there any method to access session data in the i frame?

Comment: I Don't know because i can't see the iframe. You mean a html iframe in a view?

Comment: <div class="container-fluid">
  <iframe frameborder="0" name="iframe1" width="1080px" height="560px" src="<?php echo site_url('admin/manage_profile');?>">
  </iframe>
 </div>

Comment: yes. am using the iframe in the view of the codeigniter

Comment: Try calling the session outside of the iframe, assigning a variable to the session data you want to use, then calling the variable inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know it helps or not, but one important thing is that,

If you are using an iframe and getting the contents using an ajax call this can happen. It is because session class in codeIgniter updates the session info for every `$config[‘sess_time_to_update’]` minutes.

This is a very useful security feature to thwart session hijacking.
If you are getting the details through AJAX the session is updated and a new session id is generated but the cookie in the browser is not updated.so the next time the browser requests a new page it sends a cookie with the wrong session id and the session becomes invalid resulting in loss of session data.

[This thread](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/138823/) might help you overcoming the situation.

Credits to the guy who actually found the solution.
Thanks.

Step 1:
In constants.php (application/config/) you have to add the following line to define an AJAX request.

```
// Define Ajax Request
 define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
//
```

Step 2:
Create a new file under (application/libraries) called MY_Session.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Session extends CI_Session 
{

/**
* Update an existing session
*
* @access    public
* @return    void
*/
    function sess_update()
    {
       // skip the session update if this is an AJAX call!
       if ( !IS_AJAX )
       {
           parent::sess_update();
       }
    } 

}

/* End of file MY_Session.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/MY_Session.php */
```